# How to align caption description to the left in KOMA article?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, koma-script

I would like to know how to align the caption to the left as in the `article` class, instead of aligned like shown on this picture in `scartcl` ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\setcapindent{0em}
```

A little example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcapindent{0em}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{ctanlion}
  \caption{\protect\lipsum[2]}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.